# How to specify the minimum Typescript version for types in a package?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm publishing a Typescript package, along with its Javascript compilation and a `types.d.ts` file.

My dev dependency for Typescript is at ^4.5.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "^4.5"
}
```

I had a user report a breakage in a recent update, as they are using Typescript 4.1, and my types started using a feature added in Typescript 4.4.

I don't think I can take a `peerDependency`, as use of Typescript is optional.

How can I register the minimum expected version of Typescript in my package?

Comment: You may want to add a note that this question has some overlap in _topic_ with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925443/how-to-make-4-x-typescript-project-compatible-with-older-version-of-typescript-3), but that it is not a duplicate since it is not directly asking about supporting older typescript language versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You night not have to if you're willing to put in some extra work to add support for older TypeScript type syntax.

#### The Option With no Extra Work

If you don't want to put in that work, you can just embrace it as a breaking change to stop supporting older emitted .d.ts file syntax. If your package follows [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), bump the major version and document in your changelog that there's a breaking change that typings now require typescript 4.4 or higher. This is consistent with the recommendations on [semver-ts.org in their "supported compiler versions" section](https://www.semver-ts.org/#supported-compiler-versions).

#### The Extra Work

You can support multiple typescript language versions in your emitted .d.ts files.

See [the "'Downleveling' Types" section of semver-ts.org](https://www.semver-ts.org/#downleveling-types):

> When a new version of TypeScript includes a backwards-incompatible change to *emitted type definitions*, as they did in [3.7](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33470), the strategy of changing the types directly may not work. However, it is still possible to provide backwards-compatible types, using the combination of [downlevel-dts](https://github.com/sandersn/downlevel-dts) and [typesVersions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#version-selection-with-typesversions). (In some cases, this may also require some manual tweaking of types, but this should be rare for most packages.)
>
> - The `downlevel-dts` tool allows you to take a `.d.ts` file which is not valid for an earlier version of TypeScript (e.g. the changes to class field emit mentioned in [Breaking Changes](https://www.semver-ts.org/#breaking-changes)), and emit a version which is compatible with that version. It supports targeting all TypeScript versions later than 3.4.
> - TypeScript supports using the `typesVersions` key in a `package.json` file to specify a specific set of type definitions (which may consist of one or more `.d.ts` files) which correspond to a specific TypeScript version.
>
> The recommended flow would be as follows:
>
> 1. Add `downlevel-dts`, `npm-run-all`, and `rimraf` to your dev dependencies:
>
>    ```bash
>    npm install --save-dev downlevel-dts npm-run-all rimraf
>    ```
> 2. Create a script to downlevel the types to all supported TypeScript versions:
>
>    ```bash
>    # scripts/downlevel.sh
>    npm run downlevel-dts . --to 3.7 ts3.7
>    npm run downlevel-dts . --to 3.8 ts3.8
>    npm run downlevel-dts . --to 3.9 ts3.9
>    npm run downlevel-dts . --to 4.0 ts4.0
>    ```
> 3. Update the scripts key in `package.json` to generate downleveled types generated by running `downlevel-dts` on the output from `tsc`, and to clean up the results after publication. For example, using `ember-cli-typescript`’s tooling:
>
>    ```json
>    {
>      "scripts": {
>    -   "prepublishOnly": "ember ts:precompile",
>    +   "prepublish:types": "ember ts:precompile",
>    +   "prepublish:downlevel": "./scripts/downlevel.sh",
>    +   "prepublishOnly": "run-s prepublish:types prepublish:downlevel",
>    -   "postpublish": "ember ts:clean",
>    +   "clean:ts": "ember ts:clean",
>    +   "clean:downlevel": "rimraf ./ts3.7 ./ts3.8 ./ts3.9 ./ts4.0",
>    +   "clean": "npm-run-all --aggregate-output --parallel clean:*",
>    +   "postpublish": "npm run clean",
>      }
>    }
>    ```
> 4. Add a `typesVersions` key to `package.json`, with the following contents:
>
>    ```json
>    {
>      "types": "index.d.ts",
>      "typesVersions": {
>        "3.7": { "*": ["ts3.7/*"] },
>        "3.8": { "*": ["ts3.8/*"] },
>        "3.9": { "*": ["ts3.9/*"] },
>        "4.0": { "*": ["ts4.0/*"] },
>      }
>    }
>    ```
>
>    This will tell TypeScript how to use the types generated by this process. Note that we explicitly include the `types` key so TypeScript will fall back to the defaults for `3.9` and higher.
> 5. If using the `files` key in `package.json` to specify files to include (unusual but not impossible for TypeScript-authored packages), add each of the output directories (`ts3.7`, `ts3.8`, `ts3.9`, `ts4.0`) to the list of entries.
>
> Now consumers using older versions of TypeScript will be buffered from the breaking changes in type definition emit.
>
> If the community adopts this practice broadly we will want to invest in tooling to automate support for managing dependencies, downleveling, and type tests. However, the core constraints of this RFC do not depend on such tooling existing, and the exact requirements of those tools will emerge organically as the community begins implementing this RFC's recommendations.

There are some limitations of things that can be downleveled with this approach, so make sure to read the docs of downlevel-dts to make sure you don't hit those edge cases.